# Pytorch Model Prediction on GPU or CPU speed improvement

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Running a Multi layer perceptron model on CPU is faster then running it on GPU

```
device  = torch.device("cuda")
MODEL = MLP(num_classes=len(MODEL_META["labels"])).to(device)
checkpoint = torch.load(path,map_location=device)
MODEL.load_state_dict(checkpoint)
```

i run it with current code:

```
for i in data:
    v = data[i:256]
    v = v[0:1600]
    v = np.pad(v,(0,1600-256),'constant')
    x = torch.from_numpy(v).float().view(-1,1600).to(device=device)
    with torch.no_grad():
        out = MODEL(x)
```

on the same data i have GPU finishing this loop in 3.1798946857452393
seconds
and CPU executes in 2.5446364879608154 seconds

now if i load a Convolutional neural network model trained from same data i have GPU executing in 4.280640602111816 seconds and CPU in 8.113759756088257 seconds.

Using multithreading i can split the work when running models on CPU like this:

```
for i in range threads:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_search_function,parms))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
                    


for proc in jobs:
   proc.join()
```

and just by using 2 CPU cores i have nearly GPU performance.

Running in virtual Machine (Proxmox): 12core cpu 3900x and GTX1060 6G (pass trough)  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 8g ram.

Am i doing something wrong or its the correct behaviour? Or any tips to improve performance?

Comment: It is possible that a NN runs faster on the CPU than on the GPU when the cost of transferring the data to the GPU is more than the benefit of parallelization

Comment: Another tip is to make sure you are running as large batches as possible. If your samples and network are small, then CPU can be faster. Similarly, if the number of samples in your batch is low, then CPU can be faster again since it will take time to initialize the GPU.

Comment: @zoom, what do you mean by batching? an is pass a batch of data to forward function of CNN or MLP model?

Comment: @Adiz I do not understand what you are saying. But yes, we pass batches of samples to MLPs/CNNs in PyTorch.

Answer (score 0):

@Zoom this is my NN model

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,num_classes=6):
    super(MLP,self).__init__()
   
    hidden_1 = 512
    hidden_2 = 512
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1600, 128)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128,256)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256,512)
    self.fc4 = nn.Linear(512,512)
    self.fc5 = nn.Linear(512,num_classes)
    self.droput = nn.Dropout(0.2)
    self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
    self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
    self.relu3 = nn.ReLU()
    self.softmax = nn.Softmax()

   

def forward(self,x):
    # flatten image input
    x = x.view(-1,1600)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    x = self.relu1(x)
    x = self.fc2(x)
    x = self.relu2(x)
    x = self.fc3(x)
    x = self.relu3(x)
    x = self.droput(x)
    x = self.fc5(x)
    return x
```

and i use it like this

```
device  = torch.device("cuda")
MODEL = MLP(num_classes=len(MODEL_META["labels"])).to(device)
checkpoint = torch.load(path,map_location=device)
MODEL.load_state_dict(checkpoint)

for i in data:
   v = data[i:256]
   v = v[0:1600]
   v = np.pad(v,(0,1600-256),'constant')
   x = torch.from_numpy(v).float().view(-1,1600).to(device=device)
   with torch.no_grad():
      out = MODEL(x)
```

by my understaning of batching i can pass a list of "x" tensors, and it will result in a list predictions like this:

```
L = []
for i in data:
  v = data[i:256]
  v = v[0:1600]
  v = np.pad(v,(0,1600-256),'constant')
  x = torch.from_numpy(v).float().view(-1,1600).to(device=device)
  L.append(x)
with torch.no_grad():
  out = MODEL(L)
```

where "out" will be a list of tensors of same length as input list?